# Contact creation and Fire Entry Event using API - clarififications

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

Hillo,

I'm trying to figure out how the journey process is working in general. 
Currently I have created DE, Entry Event and Journey by Journey Builder. After that I will have 3rd party app that activates journey. Actually, as I see this flow, user clicks on "Activate" button and the systems should do following steps:
1) Publishing the journey:

```
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/publishAsync/{id}?versionNumber={versionNumber}
```

2) Starting the journey: `POST /interaction/v1/events`

The main obscurity here is that when we fire event (invoke (2) call) we have to pass ContactKey attribute in JSON with POST request. I'm not sure that understand what this contact mean in journey process (who should be set up there), as we have DE with all required subscribers who should go through journey way.

Can you please explain me this place?

Thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your second point, you are referring to injecting a contact into a Journey, not starting a Journey.

If you have all your Contacts in the Event Source Data Extension (which you configured in your Event) and you just want to inject them into the Journey, then you can simply use Automation Studio and include a Fire Event Activity in the Automation. When the Event is fired, any new Contacts that have been added to the Event Source DE will be injected into the Journey. You can also use the SOAP API to run this Automation.

However, if you are are referring to an existing Contact in your Contacts Model, then I'd suggest using the [contactEvents](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactEvents.htm) method — note that you will need to create an Event in Contact Builder in order to use this method. Let me know if you need further direction on this.

Comment: Thanks Eliot. Now it makes more sense for me. So, looks like, the journey can be started using account in MC (in SOAP request), not only AppCenter one

Comment: You can use your App Center OAuth access token in SOAP requests too — in fact this is preferred rather than the legacy username/password auth. Simply change your SOAP header to look like this: `<soapenv:Header><fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">accessTokenHere</fueloauth></soapenv:Header>`